# Pronunciation of seer. Is the CMU dictionary wrong

Tags: american-english, phonetics, phonics

I was looking at how "eer" is usually pronounced and I used the CMU pronouncing dictionary (American accent). I saw that most of the time (around 95%) "ee" before "r" is pronounced /ɪ/, but there are a few words like seer for which the dictionary says that "ee" is /i/. However, when looking at the oxford dictionaries (Received Pronunciation), all the words that the CMU says that have an /i/ are indicated as being pronounced with a /ɪ/.

Is the CMU dictionary wrong or is seer (or bucaneer or puppeteer) really pronounced with /i/ while other words like steer, deer, veneer and peer are pronounced with an /ɪ/?

Some links:

- Seer, CMU /sir/:
  http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/cgi-bin/cmudict?in=seer
- Deer (~95% of the words with this pattern are pronounced like this), CMU /dɪr/:
  http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/cgi-bin/cmudict?in=deer
- Seer, oxford dictionaries (pronunciation at the bottom) /sɪə/ (non rhotic that has schwa instead of /r/ because of RP, but vowel is /ɪ/)
  https://www.lexico.com/definition/seer
- Deer, oxford dictionaries (pronunciation at the bottom) /dɪə/ (non rhotic that has schwa instead of /r/ because of RP, but vowel is /ɪ/)
  https://www.lexico.com/definition/deer

I know RP and Ame are different, but I'm adding it anyway because it supports a bit the argument saying that seer is /sɪr/

Comment: Please give links. And wouldn't '[O]xford Dictionaries' give more UK-related pronunciation?

Comment: Certainly "Received Pronunciation" would indicate a distinctly British accent: comparing British pronunciation with American will find differences, quite apart from the differing conventions in IPA.

Comment: As a standard American lunkhead it looks to me like they are all pronounced with "ear". Color me mystified with any other pronunciation.

Comment: As a seer is someone who sees (what others can't or don't see) I pronounce it the same way. I used to pronounce it like 'sear' before I realised what it means.

Comment: I have just edited the question to add links, as EdwinAshworth suggested. @WeatherVane, according to CMU, in most words with the eer pattern, pronunciation is like ear.

Comment: The Oxford/Lexico "US" pronunciation of the word does not sound right to my Midwestern ears.  I pronounce it, as Peter Shor suggested (before he deleted his comment), as *see-er* (though not in two distinct syllables).

Comment: I mean in the same way that a peer (someone who pees) is not said the same as a peer (a lord or associate).

Comment: @WeatherVane - You're going to get someone Pist.

Comment: @HotLicks at least we are barking up the same tree.

Comment: I suppose one who flees is a fleer.  That guy in the backroom at the golf course who makes tees is the custom teer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some people pronounce *seer* to rhyme with *freer* (more free), but this isn't what the CMU dictionary is talking about. The CMU dictionary encodes *freer* as F R IY ER, not F R IY R. The problem with *seer* is that the CMU dictionary is inconsistent as to how it encodes these phonemes.

The CMU dictionary has

> bier, ear, hear, here, seer, tier, weir

as /-ir/, and

> beer, cheer, clear, dear, deer, ear, fear, gear, jeer, mere, near, peer, pier, queer, rear, sear, sere, shear, sheer, smear, sneer, spear, sphere, steer, tear, veer, year

as /ɪr/.

Furthermore, *beard* is B IH R D and *bluebeard* is B L UW B IY R D.

I don't think that any Americans actually differentiate between these two sets of words, although some Americans pronounce all these words with /-ir/ and some with /-ɪr/, so either of these notations would be a reasonable representation of these words.  But the CMU dictionary is inconsistent, which is not reasonable.

Comment: Downvoter: please either explain what is wrong with this answer, or give your own answer. I don't believe that *beard* and *bluebeard* are pronounced differently in any reasonable dialect of English.

Comment: I certainly not the downvoter, but I will note that there is a slight difference in emPHAsis between "beard" and bluebeard".  The final "rd" sound is more distinct in "beard".  As for "seer", the "e" sound is "longer" (using the archaic meaning of that term for pronunciation) than most of the other examples quoted, in part because separating the "see" from the the final "r" sound leads to that pronunciation.

Comment: > "But the CMU dictionary is inconsistent, which is not reasonable." @PeterShor yep, that's what I thought, thanks. Any idea what is most common or what is considered more like the standard general american/canadian? As in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_American_English

Comment: General American is a myth, but the majority of Americans use  /- ɪr/. See this [Harvard dialect survey](http://www.benbriedis.com/phonetic/search.php) question, which uses the word *miracle*, that also has the strange pronunciation *mericle*.

Comment: Thank you. Btw, did you mean to paste a different link? I don't see a survey there.

Comment: Also, wow, I thought your alias was just a nickname, but I just saw you are THE Peter Shor. Nice. I'm a mathematician and a computer scientist myself :) Kind regards and thanks again.

Comment: Right, that's the wrong link. [This](http://dialect.redlog.net/) is the correct dialect survey link.